# NSGestureRecognizer for NSToolbarItem in customizable NSToolbar

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

NSToolbarItem is not a subclass of NSView, so it doesn't support addGuestureRecognizer method. If its NSToolbar was not customizable, it would be possible to get exact subView of NSToolbar by index and then use addGuestureRecognizer method. However if the toolbar is customizable index may vary and user may add and remove the button which requires quite a lot of code for this simple thing.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you try any of the `NSToolbarDelegate` methods? Or using the identifier or tag to identify the item?

Comment: @Wileke I haven't looked into NSToolbarDelegate, I'll see if there is something there, though I am not hopeful. For the second suggestion, I don't think it can help - I am tagging NSToolbarItem not the view, there is no connection between it and its view, if it has existed there wouldn't be any problem at all.

Comment: "The toolbar item’s content is either an NSImage or an NSView.". Drop a view or control in the toolbar and `NSToolbarItem`'s property `view` will work. It is possible to add the gesture recognizer in IB.

Comment: @Willeke this sounded more promising, but unfortunately it did not help. If you drop 'Image Toolbar Item' in IB, its view property is nil and you can't add Gesture Recognizer in IB to it. I am aware that you can do that with other controls (and I did that), but I need this look of plain NSToolbarItem not the one that contains e.g. Textured Rounded Button.

Comment: You can also use an image view or a custom view.

Comment: @Willeke thanks for this advice too, unfortunately it doesn't resolve the issue - NSImageView is much smaller when rendered in the toolbar and doesn't have template effects (like highlight on click). I would guess that the custom view would have the same issues. I think I'll give up for now unless there is some other solution.